# Which is the fastest way to add a rectangle on the front window

Tags: ios, performance, draw

We can draw rectangle on the UIImage. And we can also add a sub-view with a backgroundcolor or border. I guess there is other methods to make it, too.

Did someone try to analyze them?
Which is the fastest way?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Will this be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, drawing rectangles using Quartz engine and UIImage is more CPU intensive that using UIView. If your scene is heavy and dynamic, Quartz is the best way of doing drawings because you can update your drawings.

Using UIView is not CPU intensive, but it'll have a heavy memory foot print if you want to draw a lot of rectangles.

So, if you want to draw just one or two rectangle for GUI design, I'd say go for using UIViews. But If you are trying to do some complex drawings involving more shapes go for Quartz.